# Prove $ R \cap (B \times B) $ is partial order on B

Tags: proof-writing, relations, self-learning, order-theory

Given $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$

Let $x,y,z \in B$

So $x,y,z \in A$

1. So $(x,x) \in R $ 
   Also $(x,x) \in B \times B$. Hence follows the reflexivity.
2. Since $x,y,z  \in B$ and so in $A$. So let $xRy$ and $yRz$ so $xRz$ by transititvity of $R$. Also since $x,z \in B$ so $(x,z) \in B \times B$. So $xRz \in R \cap (B \times B)$
3. Now let  $xRy$ and $yRx$. This implies $x=y$ because $R$ is partial order on $A$ and $x,y \in A$. Also $(x,y)$  and $(y,x) \in B \times B$. How do I proceed ? Is this even correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof looks complete to me: In 3. you know that if $\left(x,\, y\right),\,\left(y,\, x\right)\,\in\, R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$ they must be in $R$ and thus the antisymmetry directly translates from $A$.

Detailed Proof, as I would write it:

Let $A$ be a set with partial order $R$. Let $B\subseteq A$.

Lemma: Then $R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$ is a partial order on $B$.

Proof:

1.) If $b\in B$ then $b\in A$ and thus $\left(b,b\right)\in R$. Thus $\left(b,b\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$. Reflexivity $\checkmark$

2.) If $\left(a,b\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$ and $\left(b,c\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$
  then $\left(a,b\right)\in R$
  and $\left(b,c\right)\in R$.

Thus $\left(a,c\right)\in R$ as $R$ is a partial order.

Also from $\left(a,b\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$
  and $\left(b,c\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$
  follows that $\left\{ a,\, b,\, c\right\} \subset B$.

Thus $\left(a,c\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$. Transitivity $\checkmark$

3.) If $\left(a,b\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$
  and $\left(b,a\right)\in R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$
  then both $\left(a,b\right)\in R$
  and $\left(b,a\right)\in R$.

Thus $b=a$ as $R$ is a partial order. Antisymmetry $\checkmark$

qed

Comment: So i donot have to use $B \times B$ for anti symmetry ?

Comment: You are always only interested in $R \cap \left(B \times B\right)$. The set product $B \times B$ is not even a subset of $R$, that is it will contain some irrelevant elements in general.

Comment: but there is intersection there

Comment: The whole deal is that $R$ is a subset of $\left(A\times A\right)$. If "something" is in $R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$ it must have been in $R$. Thus the reflexive / transitive element must have been in $R$ (1. and 2. of your prove). For 3. two pairs form an antisymmetry in $R\cap\left(B\times B\right)$ - but both must have been in $R$ where the equality of both elements of the respective pairs must hold... qed, finito

Comment: A lot of text, if you want me to write this down formally say so and i will elaborate in the answer section.

Comment: Hang around, i will just write it all down, its not much work.

Comment: are you using $ R \cap B \times B \subseteq R \cap A \times A$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77074/discussion-between-mol3574710n0fn074710n-and-freja-jessen).

Comment: The moderators will probably be mad, but chat has no MathJax as I just found out - $R \cap A \times A$ is unnecessary notation for we *know* that $R \subset A \times A$.